# Cannot bind() a socket inside Apple Calendar (dylib injection)

Tags: ios, objective-c, reverse-engineering, jailbreak, dylib

I’m trying to inspect iOS 8.1's *Apple Calendar* (`MobileCal.app`) on [Reveal](http://www.revealapp.com) following [this guide](http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2013/how-to-inspect-the-view-hierarchy-of-3rd-party-apps/).

For that, I’m injecting `libReveal.dylib` which launches its own HTTP server to which the OS X Reveal app connects to.

This technique works fine with most of iOS system apps (Phone, Notes, Reminders, etc.) but something in Calendar is preventing the HTTP server from being set up.

When Calendar is run, `libReveal.dylib` is properly injected, but then I see this on the log:

> MobileCal[5110] : ERROR: Error starting HTTP Server: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" UserInfo=0x17426aa40 {NSLocalizedDescription=Operation not permitted, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Error in bind() function}
>
> MobileCal[5110] : ERROR: Reveal server failed to start with error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" UserInfo=0x17426aa40 {NSLocalizedDescription=Operation not permitted, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Error in bind() function}

Any ideas about what could be stopping the HTTP server from being set up within Calendar? I have noticed that the `MobileCal.app` bundle has an `Entitlements.plist` file, whereas most of the other system apps don't. May this issue be related to the entitlements file?

---

I also [contacted Reveal support](http://support.revealapp.com/discussions/questions/50918-unable-to-inspect-calendar-mobilecal), they were responsive, but could not pinpoint what is causing of the problem. Using `RevealLoader` from `Cydia` produces the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right about `Entitlements.plist`. Problem is very simple - `MobileCal.app` is using custom sandbox profile.

There are actually many sandbox profiles in iOS, not just for AppStore apps. Many iOS system components use them. To know which one you need to look at the app's entitlements. More specifically, `seatbelt-profiles` key.

`MobileCal.app` is signed with `MobileCal` profile. And this is exactly why you can't use `bind()`. I suspect all networking is blocked. Same can be said about `Camera.app`. It uses `MobileSlideShow` profile which also blocks all networking.

I can think of and actually used two solutions to this problem:

1. Write a daemon. Daemon will do all the work that's blocked by sandbox profile. App and daemon will communicate through some IPC API (like notifications or mach ports). Main problem with this - IPC API could also be blocked by sandbox profile. For example, `Camera.app` sandbox blocks all IPC APIs that could send arbitary data. Only Darwin notifications work which can't send arbitary data. There are ways to solve this but it will be very ugly.
2. Resign the app with sandbox profile removed. That way the app will have access to everything and you can do all the work inside your injected dylib. This is what I use now and it works very well. It's also kind of hack but it significantly improves your code by not having to deal with IPC and it's complexity. For me it worth it.

That's all in general. For your I case I think only the second solution will work.

Of cource, just editing `Entitlements.plist` is not enough. Actual entitlements are in app's binary itself. You can resign either on your mac or on iDevice itself. On mac you have a choice of [codesign](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/codesign.1.html) and [ldid](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Ldid). On iDevice your only choice is ldid.

Let's look at how you can solve your problem with ldid. First, you dump entitlements with

```
ldid -e MobileCal > entitlements.xml
```

Then you edit dumped entitlements and resign the app binary with

```
ldid -Sentitlements.xml MobileCal
```

(Yes, there is no space between `-S` and entitlement file).

That's it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! How would one resign the app with the sandbox profile removed? I reckon that just deleting the `seatbelt-profiles` key on the `MobileCal.app` bundle on the device is not enough.

Comment: Updated the answer. Sorry, forgot to explain the actual solution.