# Using CLLocationManager in SpringBoard, but got the error with:depending on legacy on-demand authorization, which is not supported for new apps

Tags: ios8, location, cllocationmanager, theos, springboard

I'm using the CLLocationManager in SpringBoard or imagent but when I alloc the CLLocationManager, I got the error `with:depending on legacy on-demand authorization, which is not supported for new apps`.
even in locationd process, I got the same situation...

```
%hook SpringBoard
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching: (id)application {
    CLLocationManager *locationMgr = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    %orig;
}
%end
```

The question is how can I get the location information in such process? Or if I can change entitlement for the app?

Comment: Please have a look http://girijeshkumar2007.blogspot.in/2014/10/ios-8-location-services-update.html

Comment: But the problem is those are system app, i can't change their Info.plist..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all due to iOS 8 changes. On previous iOS versions at least `locationd` had `com.apple.locationd.preauthorized` entitlement which gives access to location without user permission. Now even `locationd` doesn't have it. Same with `SpringBoard` and `imagent`. Of course, being `locationd` it can access location through it's own APIs - `locationd` is the location daemon that handles everything from authorization to filtering and processing raw location data from various sources.

You can change their `Info.plist` but it will not do much - those apps will still not be authorized. With `SpringBoard` you will have to display default alert to allow it to access location. With `locationd` and `imagent` you probably can't do anything - they're daemons. Daemons doesn't have UI so they can't display any alerts to request permission. To solve this system daemons use entitlements to access something without user permission (like personal info).

Now, how you can solve it apart from requesting permission from user for `SpringBoard`:

- Write your own daemon signed with `com.apple.locationd.preauthorized` entitlement. That way you can access location without any permissions. Your daemon will be always authorized to do so by default.
- Resign system apps with `com.apple.locationd.preauthorized`. It's kind of hack, which I'm personally against of in this case as writing a daemon solves all the problems. If you still want to do it that way then read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126315/cannot-bind-a-socket-inside-apple-calendar-dylib-injection/27133879#27133879)

Comment: Thanks, problem solved by sign app with com.apple.locationd.preauthorized. Now, I'm trying to create my own daemon.